# How to sort all the JSON data into plain TXT file

Tags: json, bash, sorting, jq

I was wondering if someone could tell me how to sort the following JSON data into plain text ? I've tried with 'jq' and 'jsonv' (linux apps) but no luck.

Here's the JSON data:

```
{"@hrinn": {"host": {"1": " \"some.host.name\",", "2": " false,"}, "password": {"1": " \"123456\","}}},{"@hrinn": {"host": {"1": " \"another.host.name\",", "2": " false,""}, "password": {"1": " \"654321\","}}},{"@Abnerene": {"host": {"1": " \"example.com\",", "2": " false,"}, "username": {"1": " \"username\","}, "password": {"1": " \"password123\","}}
```

Please note that all the JSON data is all on the same line

The expected results would be:

```
hostname username password
host1.net johndoe q1w2e3
host2.com alex    qwerty
host3.org bob     123456
```

Any help would be very appreciated

Thanks

Comment: No idea what "sorting JSON data into plain text" means, so what's your expected output?

Comment: the expected output would be:

hostname username password

Comment: How does your sample json input correspond to your sample output table? They don't seem to have anything in common. Is that even valid json?

Comment: I would just use Python or Perl or Ruby or really anything else that has an actual JSON parser.

Comment: Not sure if there is a copy paste error, but that is not a valid JSON.

Comment: I don't think bash is the best tool for this. I recommend using Python, and using the `json` module. THe JSON data also doesn't match the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your example json file contains three syntax errors:

- A closing curly bracket `}` is missing at the end of text.
- There is an extra double-quote just after *false,* in the second object.
- The entire objects must be enclosed by square brackets `[]` as an array.

Then the modified json file will look like:

```
$ cat test.json
[
{"@hrinn": {"host": {"1": " \"some.host.name\",", "2": " false,"}, "password": {"1": " \"123456\","}}},
{"@hrinn": {"host": {"1": " \"another.host.name\",", "2": " false,"}, "password": {"1": " \"654321\","}}},
{"@Abnerene": {"host": {"1": " \"example.com\",", "2": " false,"}, "username": {"1": " \"username\","}, "password": {"1": " \"password123\","}}}
]
```

Note that the inserted newlines are just for human readability and have nothing to do with the parser.
Now you can feed the json file to `jq`:

```
$ jq -r '.[] | .[] | [.host["1"], .username["1"], .password["1"]] | @sh' test.json
```

which yields:

```
' "some.host.name",' null ' "123456",'
' "another.host.name",' null ' "654321",'
' "example.com",' ' "username",' ' "password123",'
```

If the values in your json file are proper ones, the result will look nicer.
Hope this helps.